# MongoDB query - if value appears in array x times

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("53ab1d2c256072374a5cc63f"),
  "title": "10% Off",
  "endDate": "2015-05-08",
  "limit" : "limited",
  "redemptions": [
    "1f7f5f96be3a",
    "kf40vksk03ps"
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("53ab1d2c25607sfdgs74a5cc63f"),
  "title": "20% Off",
  "endDate": "2015-06-07",
  "limit" : "unlimited",
  "redemptions": [
    "1f7f5f96be3a",
    "1f7f5f96be3a",
    "kf40vksk03ps"
  ]
}
```

Story: a person can redeem a coupon 2 times.  After 2 times, don't return it.
How can I check that a value appears less than 2 times??

Wish it was as easy as:

```
{ 'redemptions' : { $exists: true }, $where : 'this.redemptions.$.1f7f5f96be3a.length < 2' }
```

How can I get a count for how many times a specific value is in an array and compare on that?

**Edit**
So to add some fun. I updated my schema, so I need to put that into a conditional. If `limit = 'unlimited'` { return record } if `limit = 'limited'` { return only if array has less than 2 values = '1f7f5f96be3a'

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want with aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /* find only documents that have redemption key */
    { $match : { redemptions : { $exists: true }}},
    /* unwind the redemptions array so we can filter documents by coupons */
    { $unwind : "$redemptions" },
    /* filter only coupons you're looking for */
    { $match : { redemptions : "1f7f5f96be3a"}},
    /* group the documents back so we can calculate the count */
    { $group : { _id : "$_id",
                 title : { $first : "$title" },
                 endDate : { $first : "$endDate" },
                 count :  {$sum : 1 }}},
    /* finally, count the documents that have less than 2 coupons */
    { $match : { count : { $lt :2 }}}
]);
```

Edit:

You just need to change the $group and last $match stages:

```
{ $group : { _id : "$_id",
            title : { $first : "$title" },
            endDate : { $first : "$endDate" },
            limit : { $first : "$limit" },
            count :  {$sum : 1 }}},
/* finally, count the documents that have less than 2 coupons 
   or have limit "unlimited */
{ $match : { $or : [{ count : { $lt :2 }}, {limit : "unlimited"}]}}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, got me much closer.  So to add some fun...
I updated my schema, so I need to put that into a conditional.

if limit = 'unlimited' { return record }
if limit = 'limited' { return only if array has less than 2 values =  '1f7f5f96be3a'

Anyone of doing that.  Basically what you did but in a conditional?